# A user at higher role should have access to his subordinates records only. Is the solution to create multiple roles for the same level?

Tags: roles, role-hierarchy, country-and-state

I have the following situation for role hierarchy:

```
                World 
                  |
            -------------
            |           |
         Europe        Asia 
            |           |
    -------------   -------------
    |     |     |   |     |     |
    RU   Ger   Fra  Jap  Ch   S.Kor
    |
  ------
  |    |
 Mos  St.pet
 | |  | | |
```

At the top most level I have a user how has the right to see all. Followed by continents and then countries, cities and so on.

If you are a head at a country level, lets say Russia, you should be able to see only the records created by your subordinates at city level, that is Moscow and St. Petersburg. The same restrictions at city level applies. That is, a user belonging to a particular city should view records belonging to his subordinates and not that of his neighbouring cities subordiates' records, even if they belong to the same country.

I can achieve this with role hierarchy. But if I have all 7 continents and around 50 countries, must I create a role for each of the 50 countries and numerous cities? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your requirements so closely align with how [role hierarchies](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_roles.htm&type=5) work they would seem like the natural fit. All your work will be in defining the continents, countries, cities etc...

One way or another you are going to need that data to drive the model. You might as well use what Salesforce already provides to enforce it.

**However**, the default limit for an org is [500 Roles or Territories](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329526&type=1&mode=1). That is going to be problematic at the city level unless you apply for an increase.